# Multiple data tables in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm having problems building a data table off values that come from another data table. For example, with a black-scholes option pricing model, I first get the value of options at different strikes using a data table.

Then, if I want to price for example a call spread which is a lower strike call minus a higher strike call, I can just write a formula subtracting the two values in another cell. Next, if I want to see how the price of this call spread behaves with respect to volatility, I try to build another data table. This 2nd data table, however, is populated with all the same values even though when I change the original volatility, it does change the call spread value.

How can I do this in excel?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to really understand what you are trying to do, but I am going give you this answer because I think it might be what you are looking for.

Your version of Excel has **[What-if analysis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/introduction-to-what-if-analysis-HA010243164.aspx)** tools built in. These tools are used to view the effects of different variables on the data without making permanent changes to your data table.

> Three kinds of what-if analysis tools come with Excel: scenarios, data
>   tables, and Goal Seek. Scenarios and data tables take sets of input
>   values and determine possible results. A data table works only with
>   one or two variables, but it can accept many different values for
>   those variables. A scenario can have multiple variables, but it can
>   accommodate only up to 32 values. Goal Seek works differently from
>   scenarios and data tables in that it takes a result and determines
>   possible input values that produce that result.

Here is [another site](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/what-if-analysis.html) that explains how to use it.

Comment: Basically, x and y determine a value z. I vary x in a data table and get zx1, zx2, zx3, etc. I'm interested in the value zx1 - zx2. I want to vary y and see how the value of zx1 - zx2 changes, but since these are already the results of another data table it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to install addins, I recommend that you explore the free Microsoft addin called PowerQuery.

This is the core of Microsoft's strategy for Business Intelligence & gives you a query language (with GUI thankfully) supporting may inputs including from within your workbook and a large number of ETL and other manipulation tools.

It also provides a built-in data model that enables db-like queries and joins.